# File handling C++

Tags: c++, file-handling

I am creating iventory management system,but what happens is
the data which i am entering is not going to the file and doesn't compile.I want to know what
exactly wrong with my code.

The reason why i added that absent number of dates is to deduct it from the basic Salary.Thanks in advance.
This is my program

```
void input()
{ 
    ofstream empfile;
   empfile.open("emp.txt",ios :: app);
   cout << "Enter the National Identity Card Number of the Employer \n";
   cin >>nic;
   cout << "Enter the first name of the Employer \n";
   cin >>firstName;
   cout <<"Enter the last name of the Employer \n";
   cin >>lastName;
   cout << "Enter the date of birth [date/month/year] \n";
   cin >> dob;
   cout <<"Enter your Telephone Number \n";
   cin>> pnum;
   cout <<"Enter your address \n";
   cin >> address;
   cout <<"Your daily basic Salary is Rs20000 \n";
   cout << "How many days did she/he haven't reported to the Factory? \n";
   cin >>days;

    if(days=1)
    {
      salary=salary-1000;
    }
    else if(days<3 && days>1)
    {
        salary=salary+2000;
    }
    else if(days>=3)
    {
       salary=salary-3000;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Please enter a valid number of days \n";
    }
   empfile >> nic >> ' ' >>firstName >> ' ' >> lastName >> ' ' >> dob >> ' ' >>pnum>> ' ' >>address >> ' ' >> salary>> endl;
   empfile.close();


}
```

Comment: This doesn't give you a compilation error?

Comment: yes that's the problem

Comment: I'm curious as to why you decided to claim some other symptom in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have to is just simply turn the arrows to other side,that's why  the data wont go to the
`empfile` object

```
 empfile << nic << ' ' <<firstName << ' '<< lastName << ' '<< dob << ' '<<pnum<<' '<<address <<' '<<salary<< endl;
   empfile.close();
```